# Where should Django project files be located in a production server to allow multiple authorized users to manage?

Tags: django

If the project will be pulled from git, where should it go? I also need to give multiple authorized users to access and manage the project. Also, how should virtualenv be handled on this scenario? My default virtualenv location would be ~/.env so other users wouldn't be able to access.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think it should be as far from any /home or /root directory. Also, servers usually are placed on /etc or /var folder, like

`/etc/myservice/` <-- but only available for sysadmin and the server

`/var/myservice/` <-- access available just to `myauthorizedgroup`
It is very important to provide the read and write permissions just to the authorized users.

If you need help with permissions, [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/149404/how-can-i-create-an-ssh-user-who-only-has-permission-to-access-specific-folders) may help you.

Hope it helps :)